# BigQuery question - Attribution modeling with the paths table

Tags: google-bigquery

this may be a basic question but I just couldn't figure it out. Sample data and query could be found [here](https://developers.google.com/ads-data-hub/guides/paths#first-touch).

The purpose of query is to figure out which placement to attribute credit to. In the first-touch model, the earliest touch that led to a conversion (FLOODLIGHT) is credited. So here 22 has 1 credit, 11 has 2. I don't quite get the first-tough query especially the unnest part. What's the point of comparing `prev_conversion_event.event_time < conversion_event.event_time`? Aren't they essentially the same? I mean both of them came from `UNNEST(t.*_path.events)`. And `attributed_event.event_time` also came from the same place. I'm just confused as hell here. Much appreciate the help!

For convenience I'm pasting the sample data and query below:

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQLyi.png)

`/* Substitute *_paths for the specific paths table that you want to query. */
SELECT
  (
  SELECT
    attributed_event_metadata.placement_id
  FROM (
    SELECT
      AS STRUCT attributed_event.placement_id,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY attributed_event.event_time ASC) AS rank
    FROM
      UNNEST(t.*_paths.events) AS attributed_event
    WHERE
      attributed_event.event_type != "FLOODLIGHT"
      AND attributed_event.event_time < conversion_event.event_time
      AND attributed_event.event_time > (
      SELECT
        IFNULL( (
          SELECT
            MAX(prev_conversion_event.event_time) AS event_time
          FROM
            UNNEST(t.*_paths.events) AS prev_conversion_event
          WHERE
            prev_conversion_event.event_type = "FLOODLIGHT"
            AND prev_conversion_event.event_time < conversion_event.event_time),
          0)) ) AS attributed_event_metadata
  WHERE
    attributed_event_metadata.rank = 1) AS placement_id,
  COUNT(*) AS credit
FROM
  adh.*_paths AS t,
  UNNEST(*_paths.events) AS conversion_event
WHERE
  conversion_event.event_type = "FLOODLIGHT"
GROUP BY
  placement_id
HAVING
  placement_id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
  credit DESC`

Answer (score 1):

The point of comparing both `prev_conversion_event.event_time` and `conversion_event.event_time` is hinted at the names assigned to each value.

What we want is to find all the events between two Floodlights. Then, you need to check that your event `attributed_event` is not a Floodlight and it is between two Floodlights i.e.

```
attributed_event.event_type != "FLOODLIGHT"
attributed_event.event_time < conversion_event.event_time
attributed_event.event_time > MAX(prev_conversion_event.event_time)
```

where `MAX(prev_conversion_event.event_time)` has to reflect the previous Floodlight to the current one `conversion_event.event_time`, hence you need

```
prev_conversion_event.event_type = "FLOODLIGHT"
conversion_event.event_type = "FLOODLIGHT"
prev_conversion_event.event_time < conversion_event.event_time
```

Of course, all three elements prev_conversion, conversion and attributed are obtained from the same events (with additional filtering) hence you need to take them from the same column

```
UNNEST(t.*_paths.events) AS prev_conversion_event WHERE ...
UNNEST(t.*_paths.events) AS conversion_event WHERE ...
UNNEST(t.*_paths.events) AS attributed_event WHERE ...
```

Then, you just need to combine the previous conditions in the proper order and add the rank and the credit as appropriate for each use case (First-touch, Last-touch, Linear).

I hope that this explanation is clear enough. Let me know if something is unclear so I can help you understand it further.